# How to remember GET & POST value in php?

Tags: php, laravel

Kindly check the below code:

In filter.php

```
   <?php
   //Getting the cat_id value 25 from category.php 
   $cat_id = ((isset($_GET['cat']))?sanitize($_GET['cat']):'');
   echo 'Cart id filter page is:'.$cat_id; //25
   ?>
   <form action="FrontPageSearchFilter.php" method="post">
   <input type="hidden" name="cat" value="<?=$cat_id;?>">
   <input type="submit" value="search" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary">
   </form>
```

In search.php

```
$cat_id = (($_POST['cat'] != '')?sanitize($_POST['cat']):'');
echo 'Cart id search page is:'.$cat_id;  // 25
```

My problem is that when I click on the category it gives value 25 in filter.php

But when I click on submit button it forgets the value and pass the correct value cat_id to search.php ie: 25 but in filter.php the cat_id value becomes zero after submit button.

Here I want to remember the value even after the submit button pressed until the category doesn't change.

Kindly suggest me what I am doing wrong.
Thank You.

Comment: How to achieve it by manual function?

Comment: Most likely your server doesn't support the php Short Code of <?

Comment: @ Ross Wilson How to achieve it by making manual function in php?

Comment: As I can see the form action is "FrontPageSearchFilter.php", not "search.php", so my question is: is it the same web resource? If not, it's obvious that $_POST['cat'] is unset. Furthermore to store temporily data consider using session data.

Answer (score 0):

**localStorage**
You can also use more modern techniques like localStorage.

```
//First Grab the value of the form before it submits
var yourObject = $('#your-form').serializeArray();

//Stringify your object since that is how localstorage will save the value
localStorage['variablename'] = JSON.stringify(yourObject)

//Then retrieve that information which is a string and parse it to JS object so you could put those values in the default form.
JSON.parse(localStorage['yourObject']);
```

Every time a user submits those previous values they entered could be there all while you don't have to mess with any of you PHP submission forms.

Answer (score 0):

the issue can be with sanitize function. Try to use another?

filter.php

```
< ? php
//Getting the cat_id value 25 from category.php 
$cat_id = $_GET['cat'] + 0;
echo 'Cart id filter page is:'.$cat_id; //25
?>
<form action="search.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cat" value="<?=$cat_id;?>">
<input type="submit" value="search" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary">
</form>
```

search.php

```
< ? 
$cat_id = $_POST['cat'] + 0;
echo 'Cart id search page is:'.$cat_id;  // 25    
?>
```

If you sure that you will get only numbers in $_GET['cat'] $_POST['cat], does not matter positive or negative number, I would like suggest you just use a trick of PHP, like:
$cat = $_GET['cat'] + 0;
but be check to switch off all warnings in php.ini
It is more fluent trick, it gives you initialization of variable = 0, so you can check it by type:

```
if ($cat===0) echo 'Sorry, first select the category.';
```

or

```
if ($cat===0 and not isset($_GET['cat'])) ShowSelectCategorySidebar();
```

hope it was useful.